# ubuntu 16.04 boot option disappeared on Lenovo Y700

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lenovo

My lenovo is dual booted with Ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10, and normally when i start up, i get the Grub options to choose between these two (and some others).
but now my grub wont show, and pushing F2 to enter Bios or F12 to choose boot option says there is only Windows to open.
so im not able to boot ubuntu, only windows.
the only thing i did since i was able to boot on ubuntu was use windows for a while.

if you need outputs from files or lists ask me.
does anyone have an idea what happend or how i can fix it?

Comment: Have you noticed some big update in Windows recently? That would explain it.

Comment: nothing big, but if it did how would i fix it?

Comment: That depends on what happened. Is it UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: its in uefi mode

Comment: Try booting a live session and confirm the Ubuntu partition are still there. If so try `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: like use my usb i used to install ubuntu? and open a try ubuntu session or what?

Comment: Yes, that's a live session

Comment: i get /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow.

Comment: and it says there is 485gb Volume partition (which contains my ubuntu files)

Comment: Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: an error occurred during the boot repair and it wasnt able to make a pastebin with the file, but i have the error file saved. how do i upload the error file or which lines do you need to know what went wrong?

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23783381/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51625/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-bartolo-05).